# Microsoft has blocked the ability to authenticate Azure via Keycloak in the iframe due to a clickjack vulnerability

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I am encountering an issue with using an iframe to open the Keycloak login screen in my application. However, Microsoft has blocked the ability to authenticate Azure via Keycloak in the iframe due to a clickjack vulnerability. Could someone please provide guidance or assistance in resolving this issue?

In an attempt to resolve this issue, I referred to some code references from the internet and made modifications to the login.ftl file of my custom login theme. I added JavaScript code and changed the login theme to a custom one. However, I encountered an error stating "An internal server error has occurred."

i am using keycloak version as 12.0.4 and operating system is ubuntu

The code snippet that resulted in the error is as follows:

```
<a onclick="openInPopUp('${p.loginUrl}', '${name}')" id="zocial-${p.alias}" class="zocial ${p.providerId}"></a>


function openInPopUp(url, name) {
let popup = window.open(url, name, 'toolbar=no,width=600,height=600');
let receiveMessage = (event) => {
  if (event.origin !== (window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname)){
    return;
  }
  document.forms['kc_social_continue'].action = event.data;
  document.forms['kc_social_continue'].submit();
};
window.addEventListener('message', receiveMessage, false);
}
```